# Form: Tabular arrangement of 'TextField's and digsigfield

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe

**I use digsig.sty from Martin Lottermoser
http://home.htp-tel.de/lottermose2/tex/dist/digsig.sty**

---

How can I arrange two 'TextField's and one digsigfield in this shape, as seamlessly as possible?

[image]

---

**MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, 
showframe=false
%headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{digsig} 

\begin{document}
Please describe your observation as accurately as possible:\par
\begin{Form}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.5\textwidth}  X }
\noindent\color{red}\fbox{\noindent\digsigfield{0.5\textwidth}{10cm}{test}} & \TextField[multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1, height=10cm]{}\\
\TextField[multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 2, height=7cm, width=\textwidth]{}{} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to complicate things by using a tabular.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot,
showframe=false
%headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{digsig}

\begin{document}
Please describe your observation as accurately as possible:\par
\begin{Form}
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2}
\noindent
\color{red}\fbox{\digsigfield{0.5\textwidth}{10cm}{test}}%
\TextField[name=text1,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1, height=10cm,width=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{}\\
\TextField[name=text2,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 2, height=7cm, width=\textwidth]{}{}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike Fischer     But it seems this is not 100%: <br> 
[![IMAGE][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjq03.png

Comment: pdf borders and fbox borders are different, and the first type even depends on the viewer. If you don't want to fiddle with this, use \fbox for the textfields too (and don't forget to substract the additional fboxsep/fboxrule).

Comment: `"use \fbox for the textfields too"`  this becomes worst...

Comment: Set the border color to white: `bordercolor= 1 1 1`.

Comment: I should not say `\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2}`. So I think, it is better to search for a table solution.

Comment: If you don't redefine the layout (at least locally) you will also in a table run into the problem that there are perhaps unwanted spaces (and naturally will have to handle all the spaces the tabular code inserts).

Comment: I hate the Forms!  I need something like a t-column: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StjIA.png

Comment: Maybe with annother kind of table. I do not know all the tables there are (only tabular and tabularx) :(

Comment: No table will help you with the task that you need to get the size of the fields right. Why you are always trying to avoid to solve the core problem?

Comment: 1. Because I am bad. 2. The core-problem is: how to serve that into a table. This is better, thrust me. 


It may be that the proposed method just works here. But with the smallest changes, as to the arrangement, it flies but just so enter around the ears. I am surprised that you propose that as a solution at all.

Comment: You can put the things in a table later. Your first problem is to get the size of fields right.

Comment: I can not work with this solution.