# Form: 'TextField's and digsigfield in a table

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe, javascript

Note: Question is kin to [Form: Tabular arrangement of 'TextField's and digsigfield](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468568/form-tabular-arrangement-of-textfields-and-digsigfield/468574?noredirect=1#comment1179434_468574)

**I use digsig.sty from Martin Lottermoser
http://home.htp-tel.de/lottermose2/tex/dist/digsig.sty**

---

How can I arrange two 'TextField's and one digsigfield in this shape, as seamlessly as possible?

I think, I have to set a correct value into 
`\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr 0\fboxsep+1\fboxrule+\arrayrulewidth}`
?

**BTW:** I have to implement this with a table, because the picture is only a possible special case.

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, 
showframe=false
%headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{digsig} 

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
  \setlength\fboxrule{\arrayrulewidth}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr 0\fboxsep+1\fboxrule+\arrayrulewidth}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{b{0.5\textwidth}  X }
\noindent\color{blue}\fbox{\noindent\digsigfield{0.5\textwidth}{10cm}{test}} & \TextField[multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1, height=10cm]{}\\
\TextField[multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 2, height=7cm, width=\textwidth]{}{} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textfields must have a name!

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot,
showframe=false
%headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{digsig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % yes you need this
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
  \setlength\fboxrule{\arrayrulewidth}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5\fboxrule}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{b{0.5\textwidth}  X }
\noindent\color{blue}\fbox{\noindent\digsigfield{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule}{10cm}{test}} &
\noindent\TextField[name=box1,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1, height=10cm]{}\\[-0.3\normalbaselineskip]
\hspace{\fboxrule}\TextField[name=box2,multiline,borderstyle=S, 
             value=Text 2, height=7cm, width=\textwidth]{}{}
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, I will call my TexTField 'Ulrike Fischer' :()

Comment: There need different names - unless you want every textfield to show the same content (try it out, name both box1 and then enter something in one of the fields ...). And better don't use spaces or something. This names are stored in the pdf.

Comment: I forgot the names, because I create the Textfields with a newcommand. This has the background, that I do not know how I can change the font globaly for all Textfields without processing their names. BTW: This could be an interesstig question, I will open a thread.